# Search without redirecting to a specific tag?

Tags: support, search

If I search for `kiosk` on StackOverflow, I get redirected to an empty tag.  Instead, I would like the search results for the general term, `kiosk`.

Is there a way to force the search function to not redirect to a tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching for "stack overflow" redirects me to the \[stackoverflow\] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258980/searching-for-stack-overflow-redirects-me-to-the-stackoverflow-tag)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Search for the phrase ["kiosk"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22kiosk%22) (with the quotes) instead, as per the [Search Options page](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

You can also use the "force the word to be present" syntax: [+kiosk](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bkiosk).