# Searching for "stack overflow" redirects me to the [stackoverflow] tag

Tags: support, search, tag-search, redirection

I searched for "stack overflow" in the search bar, but it doesn't list the results normally. Instead, it redirects me to the tag [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow).

Why is this happening, and how can I search for posts literally containing "stack overflow"?

Comment: Your desire doesn't make much sense. You want questions about Stack Overflow... The [tag:stackoverflow] tag here on Meta is exactly *for* questions which are about Stack Overflow. Why would you want to search for the words instead?

Comment: Because the search results tell me to go to stackoverflow.com. I want to go flaggin' people on MSE talking about SO. Flaggin', flaggin'! Yeah!

Comment: It doesn't redirect you to stackoverflow.com, it's just a message to try and get people to post new questions in the appropriate place. The tag search still gives you a list of all the questions with the tag.

Comment: I know it doesn't, but it won't show search results and all it says is to go to stackoverflow.com for those questions.

Comment: It shows over 5,000 results... What page are you looking at? Are you sure you're not on the featured tab or something?

Comment: There is no featured tab, and it says I'm on the featured tab.

Comment: It remembers what tab you were on before. So if you went to the featured tab previously and then searched for something that yields no featured questions, you end up with a blank page and an invisible tab. Just click on one of the others and you should see everything fine.

Comment: But there's another bug: why isn't the featured tab visible?

Comment: Why do you need to search for questions to flag?  Don't waste people's time looking for old MSE posts just for the purposes of flagging them

Comment: @AIE that is quite confusing, since searching with quotes does not redirect to the tag page.

Comment: @Brad I flagged the other question as a duplicate of this question. Why does it always backfire on me?

Comment: Probably because the other question has been there for 7+ years and has more votes and such?

Comment: @Brad There are also 2 questions linked as duplicates of this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the default behavior - if the search term happens to be one of the top 40 tags, you are redirected to that tag's page.

If you really want to search for the word "stackoverflow", put it between quotes:  [`"stackoverflow"`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22stackoverflow%22).

Comment: That actually only happens if the search term matches one of the top 40 tags for the site.

Comment: @ani Thanks for noticing this!

Comment: OP knows this - this question is actually a feature request asking to change this.

Comment: @nicael I was just trying to point out that it only happens for the top 40 tags. The [tag:stackoverflow] tag is the sixth top tag here on Meta, so it should happen here. It wouldn't on Stack Overflow, though.

Comment: @ani LOL and I've browsed SO. Okay.

Comment: @Sha who said that?.. He doesn't.