# Searching for a tag inconsistently redirects to the tag page

Tags: support, tags, search

Searching for a word that matches an existing tag should, I believe, redirect you to the tag page for that tag, instead of a regular search result.

This is happening inconsistently...

For example, a search for the word "search" doesn't redirect to the tag page:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=search
>
> [image]

But a search for "support" *does* redirect to the tag page:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=support
>
> [image]

I tested this on a few sites with a number of tags and can reproduce on at least three sites (I couldn't on one). It also seems to be more inconsistent on some sites than others.

Why do only some tags redirect to the tag page?

Comment: I _think_ that only happens for tags that are in the top 20 tags, or something like that. (Looking for confirmation.)

Comment: Ah, here we go. It's actually [Top 40](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258981/21960).

Comment: @ale ah OK, looks like "search" is in the top 40 tags here though....

Comment: looks like it's actually 80 on most sites, but 20 on MSE and 120 on SO

Comment: That's not a discussion by far. Either support or feature request.

Comment: @Cai where you got those numbers? It appears to be 40, on all sites. If you have proof for the other numbers, please post a new answer in the dupe, or edit the existing answer.

Comment: @Sha you can just go to the [list of tags](/tags) and count then search to check. e.g on GD #80 will redirect https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=typesetting and #81 won't https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=file-format